# Only display the template but now dummy data that I have

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I just start learning React. I m trying to make a Notifications page that data would be in Notifications.jsx and the display with the content in card template and it only shows the template but not with the dummy data.
Here are the code **Notifications.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NotificationsCard from "./NotificationsCard/NotificationsCard"
import "./Notifications.css";


class Notifications extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
        alert: [],
        alertList : [
            {
                type: "Expiration",
                tags: [
                {
                detail: "Expiration Alert | Date | Time", 
                content:"Apples are about to expire in 4 days!",
                image:"//images.albertsons-media.com/is/image/ABS/184020020?$ecom-pdp-desktop$&amp;defaultImage=Not_Available&amp;defaultImage=Not_Available"
                }]
            },
            {
                type: "Receipt",
                tags: [
                {
                detail: "Receipt added | Date | Time", 
                content:"(Custom receipt name) is added!",
                image:"https://www.grocerycouponguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/safeway-receipt.jpg"
                }]
            },
            {
                type: "Low Count",
                tags: [
                {
                detail: "Low Count Alert | Date | Time", 
                content:"Onion is running low!",
                image:"//images.albertsons-media.com/is/image/ABS/184450054?$ecom-pdp-desktop$&amp;defaultImage=Not_Available&amp;defaultImage=Not_Available"
                }]
            }
        ]

    }

}
render() { 
    const { alertList } = this.state;
    const {alert} = this.state;

    return (            
      <>
      <div>
      {this.state.alertList.map((alertList) =>
        <NotificationsCard key={alertList.type} alert={alertList} />       
        )}        
      </div>
      <div>
  </div>

     </>
    )


    }};
```

export default Notifications;

**NotificationsCard.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./NotificationsCard.css";


class NotificationsCard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { 

}
}

onReadClick = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("SAR button clicked");
};

onDismissClick = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("Dismiss button clicked");
};




render() {

return (
  <div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <img src={this.props.alert.image} />
    </div>
    <div >
      <b >{this.props.alert.detail}</b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>content: {this.props.alert.content}</b>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onClick = {this.onReadClick}>SET AS READ</button>
    <button onClick = {this.onDismissClick}>DISMISS</button>
  </div>
</div>
);
};
}

export default NotificationsCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing your properties the right way. You should call `this.props.alert.tags[0].YOUR_PROPERTY` or loop through tags. Something like this :

```
render() {
    console.log('notif', this.props.alert)

    return (
      <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src={this.props.alert.tags[0].image} />
        </div>
        <div >
          <b >{this.props.alert.tags[0].detail}</b>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>content: {this.props.alert.tags[0].content}</b>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick = {this.onReadClick}>SET AS READ</button>
        <button onClick = {this.onDismissClick}>DISMISS</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  };
```

Here is a working example on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ysu8f?file=index.js